# Trouble sorting JSON object

Tags: jquery, sorting

I have a JSON object collection:

```
var Gallery = [
    { "Order": 1, "Page": 1, "LargeImage": "large.jpg", "ThumbImage": "thumb.jpg" }, 
    { "Order": 2, "Page": 1, "LargeImage": "large2.jpg", "ThumbImage": "thumb2.jpg" }];
```

I want to each over this object but after the collection is sorted on "Order".  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort the Array, try this:

```
Gallery.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.Order - b.Order;
});
```

But be sure to test the result in IE, as it can be a little funny with `.sort()`.

Then use `$.each()` like normal to iterate over the Array.